# Adding and Removing Validation using RegEx on Input Fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, validation

I have a dialog box that pops up after hitting an Add button. There are 2 fields, MR ID and Supplier ID. MR ID is a dropdown and shouldn't need any sort of validation. The supplier id is a text input and needs validation. It needs to be numbers only and there also can be no 2 supplier ids that are the same. They must be all unique. The code I have so far does not work in validating the supplier id.

HTML/PHP for dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Supplier ID">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">MR_ID</label>
      <select name="mr_id" id="mr_id_dialog" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="300">
          <?php foreach($user->fetchAll() as $user1) { ?>
            <option selectedvalue="1">
                <?php echo $user1['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="buyer_id">Supplier ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="supp_id" id="supplier_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Dialog Box for adding supplier id -----

$( function() {


    $("#insertButton").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });   

    var dialog, form,

      mr_id_dialog = $( "#mr_id_dialog" ),
      supplier_id = $( "#supplier_id" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_id_dialog ).add( supplier_id ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.value ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      //valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_id_dialog, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid MR ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( supplier_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Supplier ID" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#index_table tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+supplier_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "mr_id_dialog":
                dict["MR_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "supplier_id":
                dict["Supp_ID"] = value;
              break;
            }
        });
        $( "#index_table tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);

        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Supplier ID": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( "#insertButton" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          position: ['center', 'top'],
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Samples that should pass:

```
349348
2
1234
```

Samples that should not pass:

```
01234
123 45 67
No hyphens, dashes, etc. Numbers only.
```

Comment: Please add to your description the expected input format for the _Supplier ID_ field (e.g. `3 7`?). I created [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKk4sQI40S88BtA8Q8HN?p=preview) with your sample code. Feel free to update/fork that and use it in your description

Comment: The input can be any sort of numbers, but not beginning with 0

Comment: Your description contains _there also can be no 2 supplier ids that are the same_ - are the supplier ids in that one string of numbers? or do you mean _each digit_ must be unique?

Comment: each supplier id as a whole must be unique....there CAN be same digits in one supplier ID

Comment: Please provide samples of input that should pass and not pass the test (e.g. _123_ should pass, _993 2_ should fail, etc).

Comment: Added samples in original code

Answer (score 1):

Per [the jQuery documentation for the id-selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Calling `jQuery()` (or `$()`) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element.

Instead of using the *value* property of the *supplier_id*, use the [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function - because .val() will:

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements

So update your function checkRegexp() like this:

```
function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
  if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
  ...
```

Also, when generating the [*option*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements for the select list, *selectedvalue* is not a valid attribute. There are 4 attribute specific to *option* elements (in addition to the [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)): *disabled*, *label*, *selected* and *value*.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#insertButton").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });   
    var dialog, form,
      mr_id_dialog = $( "#mr_id_dialog" ),
      supplier_id = $( "#supplier_id" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_id_dialog ).add( supplier_id ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( supplier_id, /^([1-9][0-9]*)$/g, "Please enter a valid Supplier ID" );
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#index_table tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+supplier_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "mr_id_dialog":
                dict["MR_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "supplier_id":
                dict["Supp_ID"] = value;
              break;
            }
        });
        $( "#index_table tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      $('#console').append('valid: '+valid+'<br />');
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Supplier ID": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( "#insertButton" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          position: ['center', 'top'],
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

```css
#console {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="insertButton">Insert</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Supplier ID">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
  <!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">MR_ID</label>
      <select name="mr_id" id="mr_id_dialog" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="300">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="buyer_id">Supplier ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="supp_id" id="supplier_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99" />
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

**Edit**: in your comments, you mentioned you have it mostly working though it doesn't accept zero followed by other digits but it does accept a single 0 (i.e. `0`). If you remove the zero and the pipe from your regex, that should suffice. So the regex goes from:

```
/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/
```

to

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*)$/
```

```js
var nums = ['123', '99', '01234', '0', '00', '993 2'];
var pattern = /^([1-9][0-9]*)$/;
nums.forEach(function(numberString) {
  console.log('num: ',numberString,' pattern match: ',pattern.test(numberString));
  });
```

Comment: The validation still is not working...wouldnt there have to be more changed then just the `o.value` changing to `o.val`?

Comment: perhaps it was also that I changed the first line to wait until the DOM is ready - see the updated explanation

Comment: this definitely works in your code snippet, but if i copy and paste the code in to my code, it still doesnt work....any idea why?

Comment: Hmm I am not really sure... Maybe try starting with my code and then slowly add in your pieces ensuring it still works along the way. I can try to make an example with Ajax enabled later today.

Comment: I made separate test files with just your code and it doesnt work...so it works here but not in separate code that I just made myself...hmm

Comment: Okay, I must have missed the parentheses in the `o.val()` because it partially works now. The only thing that needs fixed now is, while it wont take a number starting with a 0, (ie. 01234), it will take just the number 0 itself. Also, it will also still take a Supp_ID that is already in the table which cant happen because they need to be unique.

Comment: Okay see my new last paragraph about updating the regular expression pattern. As far as preventing existing values from being accepted, you could store those in a javascript variable (e.g. array, hash, etc) to ensure that the given value is not in the array, but if you don't want those accessible to users, then you would need to have a server-side check (perhaps called via AJAX) to check if the value exists... that could incorporated with the call to save (i.e. *insert.php*)...